# Grails 3 Asset Pipeline in production producing wrong URLs and 404ing

Tags: tomcat, nginx, grails, asset-pipeline

So, I just tried releasing a 3.2.6 web app in production mode (war on tomcat) and all assets are 404ing.

When I open the unpacked folder in tomcat webapps, under assets i see all the js and css files fine.

After some digging I found the asset pipeline is hrefing the files as `/app-name/assets/...`, but my app is running on a root domain, so when I tried `/assets/something.css` I got the file fine.
I've serverUrl set for production properly as `https://example.com/`

I couldn't find anything on this in the Asset Pipeline [docs](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#configuration-2). Any help is appreciated.

---

Additional info about production setup: app in tomcat is running under `/app-name/` but theres an nginx reverse proxy set up for `example.com/` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this fixed it:
application.yml: `assets.url: https://example.com/assets/`